# how to enable 64 platform on visual studio 2010

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio

I am working on visual studio 2010

and i have this option

[image]

as you see, the platform is `Active (x86)`, how can I change it to 64 please?

I am working on visual studio 2010 on windows 7 64bit

Comment: The platform name in that combobox is irrelevant for C# projects, it only matters for C++ projects.  So just don't bother, only the Platform target setting on your EXE project is important.  Do favor "Any CPU" over x64 so it always works.

Answer (score 0):

You're looking at the difference between the actual settings and the configuration/platform.

In most respects, the `configuration` (Debug, Release, ect.) and the `platform` (x86, Any CPU, Mixed Platforms, ect.) are actually arbitrary names, though Visual Studio does some work for you if you use them a certain way. This can be useful for times like game or plugin development, when `Platform` or `Configuration` might actually need to be operating system or program version being developed for.

As long as the project's Properties page (for a given Configuration/release combination) states `x64`, then you're building an `x64` project regardless of what the `Platform` says.

If you want to edit `Configuration` and `Platform` names to avoid confusion, drop down one of the two of those options in the main bar, or right click your solution, and select `Configuration Manager`. This will give you the options to add or rename solution level platforms.

If you want to rename the platforms as they appear on individual projects, you'll need to open your .CSProj file; it's actually in XML, so any text editor will do, or VS if you right-click -> `unload project` first. Once there, replace all references to a given platform with a desired name, or make references to a desired name to add it.

Answer (score 0):

What you have done there is set the Release x86 configuration to compile to 64 bit. This is probably not what you intended. First change the Platform Target back to x86 to keep the x86 configuration set to a 32 bit process.

Once you have done this come out of the project settings and right click on the solution file and select "Configuration Manager...". Drop down the "Active solution platform" in the top right. If you don't have an x64 configuration listed select "". Give it the name x64 then select to copy the settings from x86. Press Ok a couple of times to come out of the settings.

Now go back into your project settings and you should have an x64 option in the Platform dropdown. Select it. Then switch to the Build tab as you have done and select x64 from the Platform target list.

Comment: i got error when i select the `x64` that it is alredy exsited :( , i am out of my mind, it is been two days, i finished my project and still just the deployment, could you pleae access my machine and do it? please please

Answer (score 0):

Right click on your solution and choose **Configuration Manager** option. Then at **Active solution platform** choose **New** option.
[image]

In the next dialog, for **Type and select the new platform** choose **x64**.
Then, set the proper value for **Copy settings from** and leave the check box **Create new project platforms** selected. After that, click **OK**.

[image]

Comment: i have done this, i got error message that the same name already exsits

Comment: pleaes can i give you a team viewer to my machine and you help me? please

Comment: if it says that the name already exists, try the steps described above, but uncheck Create new project platforms